# Workflow to count items in a folder using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, count

I need help writing a workflow that will look in a folder, and count the number of instances for a specific document form type.  Such as, for all of the files in this folder, how many of them are form type b. set this number to VariableX.

I've been searching for this online, and i'm not grasping something. I think i need to build a dictionary and somehow filter it, but i'm not sure how. Thanks.

Comment: which version are you of ShP designer? if 2013 you could start with Loop command. More about Loop is here https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810296/how-to-perform-looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013-designer-workflows

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using a workaround thanks.

Comment: Post your work around here. So that others will know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

My resolve was to use workflows which run daily based off of retention. files i didn't want to count were moved into a different folder with a file content type workflow. Files I wanted to count were counted based off of file child count with a folder content type work flow.